add_attachment hook not firing on certain devices
I am developing a plugin for a client, and we are using the add_attachment hook to extract metadata from the images that we process as part of the plugin.
The funny thing is that the hook successfully fires on all of my devices (tested from both Asia and  Amsterdam), but it doesn't fire on my client's device (Germany). This is causing a certain functionality in the plugin to not work.
I suspected that this may be a difference in Javascript execution, so we looked at the browser Console. I found that on my client's device, this Console error is also registered:
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () (default.editor.min.js.map, line 0)
https://widgets.wp.com/wpcom-block-editor/default.editor.min.js.map

The https://widgets.wp.com/wpcom-block-editor/default.editor.min.js URL loads though on their end though, and I don't think the source map affects the Javascript end of things. Their browser is also not running any extensions.
Any idea what could be the issue here? The console has no other errors.
Update: Here's a shortened version of our code. We basically want to check the image's IPTC data to see if it belongs to the brand we want to detect. The EXIF::get_original_image_data() function gets the original image instead of the scaled one, so that the metadata we want to find still exists.
I've removed all mentions of the brand name because I'm not at liberty to expose that. For my devices, both after_setup_theme and add_attachment fires when I upload images, but only after_setup_theme fires for my client.
class Admin {

    const DEBUG_MODE = false;

    static function after_setup_theme() {
        require_once 'EXIF.php';

        $user = get_current_user_id();
        error_log("0: add_attachment hook added by Attachments/Admin for user $user." . PHP_EOL, 3, ABSPATH . 'error.log');

        add_action('add_attachment', array(__CLASS__,'add_attachment'), 10203, 1);
    }
    
    static function add_attachment($attachment_id) {
        
        error_log("0: add_attachment hook fired for $attachment_id." . PHP_EOL, 3, ABSPATH . 'error.log');
        
        // If the iptcparse function is not enabled, stop running this.
        if(!function_exists('\iptcparse')) {
            error_log("1: iptcparse() function does not exist. Failed processing metadata for $attachment_id." . PHP_EOL, 3, ABSPATH . 'error.log');
            return;
        }
        
        if(get_post_meta($attachment_id, 'IMAGE_META_ID')) {
            error_log("2: Meta ID already exists for this attachment ($attachment_id). Aborted." . PHP_EOL, 3, ABSPATH . 'error.log');
            return;
        }
        
        $attached_file = EXIF::get_original_image_file($attachment_id);
        
        // Check if the uploaded file is an image
        if(!empty($attached_file)) {
            
            // Read image metadata
            $size = getimagesize($attached_file, $info);
            $iptc = empty($info['APP13']) ? false : iptcparse( $info['APP13'] );
            
            // If there is IPTC data, then process to see whether it has metadata for an image ID.
            if ($iptc !== false) {
                
                // Retrieve IPTC data.
                $object_name = !empty($iptc['2#005'][0]) ? $iptc['2#005'][0] : false;
                $category = !empty($iptc['2#015'][0]) ? substr($iptc['2#015'][0],0,2) : false;
                
                // Check object_name key to see if it is an image from our brand.
                if(!empty($object_name) && !empty($category) && preg_match('@brand images ([0-9]+)@i', $object_name, $matches)) {
                    
                    // If the match is empty, return.
                    $brand_id = intval($matches[1]);
                    if(empty($matches[1])) return;
                    
                    // Otherwise get the type.
                    if(in_array($category, array('st','sp'))) $db = $category;
                    else $db = API::check_image_type($brand_id);
                    update_post_meta($attachment_id, 'IMAGE_META_ID', $db . '/' . $brand_id);
                    
                    // If there is a valid caption, add those as well.
                    $caption = empty($iptc['2#120'][0]) ? (empty($iptc['2#105'][0]) ? '' : $iptc['2#105'][0]) : $iptc['2#120'][0];
                    if(!empty($caption)) {
                        update_post_meta($attachment_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', $caption);
                    } else error_log("6: No caption IPTC for $attachment_id." . PHP_EOL, 3, ABSPATH . 'error.log');
                    
                    // If there is a valid description, add those as well.
                    $credit = empty($iptc['2#80'][0]) ? (empty($iptc['2#110'][0]) ? '' : $iptc['2#110'][0]) : $iptc['2#80'][0];
                    if(!empty($credit)) {
                        wp_update_post(array(
                            'ID' => $attachment_id,
                            'post_content' => $credit
                        ));
                    } else error_log("7: No description IPTC for $attachment_id." . PHP_EOL, 3, ABSPATH . 'error.log');
                } else error_log("5: Attached file has no brand IPTC data $attachment_id." . PHP_EOL, 3, ABSPATH . 'error.log');
            } else error_log("4: No IPTC data for $attachment_id." . PHP_EOL, 3, ABSPATH . 'error.log');
        } else error_log("3: Attached file does not exist for $attachment_id." . PHP_EOL, 3, ABSPATH . 'error.log');
    }
}


PHP hooks/actions don't happen on the device loading the page, they happen on the server. Are you using the WordPress.com service to host your site? There's no code to debug or work with in your question, can you edit it in? Have you checked the PHP error log?

Nope, the site is self-hosted. There are no errors in the PHP error log as well. We did some logging whenever an upload is made, and what we found was that for my client, the script that hooks the add_action( 'add_attachment', ... ) hook works, but the add_attachment hook itself doesn't work on their devices (it only works on mine).
As you said, PHP runs on the server-side, so I'm baffled that the hooks work on 1 device and not on another. That was why I postulated that it must be something to do with the Javascript, since the add_attachment hook is fired by the Media Library.

can you edit the code for this hook into your question

@TomJNowell it's been added. Thanks for your help.

Are you using the error_log in the add_attachment  method to test if add_action was triggered or not? How is your client adding images is this via the media library or via another mechanism? Note that if requiring EXIF.php fails then the add_action line is never reached. I'd also note that WordPress itself has EXIF parsing capabilities, loading your own isn't necessary. Have you asked your client to demonstrate this in a screenshare so that you can eliminate UI/UX differences? E.g. sometimes clients use the mobile app not WP Admin or they might be using custom plugin UI that bypasses

Yup, the add_attachment action completely doesn't fire for my client (the add_attachment hook fired... message never shows up), but no errors regarding any of the actions occur as well. The EXIF.php script is there to standardise the reading of the files (we read file metadata in multiple places), as well as because we need to retrieve the original image filepath (not the -scaled one). I'm probably just gonna hook the action to something else at this rate. I can't identify what the issue is.

Assuming the PHP error log doesn't show anything useful then I don't think this is answerable with the available information
